# textarea enriquecido en wordpress

Tags: php, html, html5, wordpress

Quiero saber como aplicar el **wp_editor** a un textarea en **wordpress**. Estoy haciendo un formulario directamente desde código y me gustaría que el **textarea** que estoy declarando este enriquecido.

Aquí el código:

```
<div class="panel panel-default"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
            <div class="wrap"> 
                <label>
                    <h4> 
                        <strong> Háblanos de ti </strong> 
                    </h4> 
                </label> 
                <div class="wp_editor">
                    <textarea name="comentarios" rows="20" cols="60">Escribe aquí algo sobre ti
                    </textarea> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><br>
```

De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Te recomiendo que des mas detalles de tu pregunta así como agregar el código correspondiente que lleves avanzado de tu proyecto para que sea mas sencillo ayudarte con tu consulta.

Comment: @ASASCED el codigo que estoy usando para el formulario es el siguiente: `<div class="panel panel-default"> <div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"> <div class="wrap"> <label><h4> <strong> Háblanos de ti </strong> </h4> </label>  <div class="wp_editor"><textarea name="comentarios" rows="20" cols="60">Escribe aquí algo sobre ti</textarea> </div></div></div></div></div><br>` lo que busco es que el textarea salga enriquecido para poder aplicar negrita y otros formatos

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas decirle a wordpress que enseñe el editor de WYSIWYG:

```
<?php 
$settings = array(
    'teeny' => true,
    'textarea_rows' => 15,
    'tabindex' => 1
);
wp_editor(esc_html( __(get_option('whatever_you_need', 'whatever'))), 'terms_wp_content', $settings);
?>
```

Comment: una consulta en donde dice 'whatever_you_need' es el nombre del textarea o el id.

Comment: Normalmente suele ser el mismo, pero es el name